# Wrapped input in a button, respond on button click

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to achieve is consistent behavior. When we click the input field the color picker shows up. I would like the same behavior when I am clicking the button that wraps it.

```
<button class="btn btn-small my-btn">
  Color <input type="color" value="#33aabb">
</button>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/topless/J73dK/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just defer to the input's `.click()`
http://jsfiddle.net/J73dK/1/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<button class="btn btn-small my-btn" onclick="this.querySelector('input').click()">
    Color <input type="color" value="#33aabb">
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C2wj2/